# How to convert from String to Integer, and use the converted string in a math operation?

Tags: java

I want to add 1 to the value the user enter. But the code avobe do not work. This program is for practice purpose just to know how to use a converted string in a math operation;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String a = scan.next();

        Integer.parseInt(a);

        int total = a + 1;
        System.out.println(total);  
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` *returns* a number, which you can assign to another variable of numeric type. `a` is a string, you don't want to add `1` to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Integer.parseInt` function returns an `int` value, but it doesn't mutate its argument in any way. You need to *assign* the result of `parseInt` to a variable or use it directly in an expression, like this:

```
int total = Integer.parseInt(a) + 1;
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) doesn't convert the variable into an `int`; it returns the converted `int`.  Besides, `String`s are immutable.

Instead of

```
Integer.parseInt(a);
int total = a + 1;
```

Try

```
int total = Integer.parseInt(a) + 1;
```